# How to compare two risk ratios using their 95% CIs

Tags: confidence-interval, p-value, stata

How do I calculate the p value for a comparison of two independent risk ratios knowing only the ratios and their 95% confidence intervals?

For example: 1.613 (95% CI 1.146-2.272) versus 0.518 (95% CI 0.325-0.824).

I have access to Stata.